# Lethal Company modded (r2modman)

Tags: games, steam, opengl

I want to play Lethal Company from Steam modded with r2modman, but when I start the game from r2modman, I get this error message.

> You are missing the following libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1

After I click OK, Steam starts to run but then it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

libGL.so.1 is provided by the libgl package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgl primus-libs
```